# @Schedule starts twice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

this program starts every day at 4 am, but every day the schedule is started twice, I have already checked any cycle but everything is in order.
why does it always start twice?
how can i solve?

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class RichiamiSync {
    @Schedule (minute = "00", hour = "04")

    public  void main() {

        try {
            Logica.esegui();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.write("ERROR  " + e);
                Log.write("---------------------ERRORE FATALE IL PROGRAMMA E' STATO ARRESTATO-------------------------");   
                }
        Ottimizza.sql();

        Log.sendEmail();


    }




}
```

initially the methods were noted like this:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

but in another question they said that with stateless it would be solved, now the problem is always the same

Comment: One possibility is that the task is started (once) but during its execution it fails with an application exception. The container could be configured to _retry_ the task which might succeed or fail again. Either way, depending on the task performed in `Logica.esegui();`, the observed behavior would be that the task fired twice (i.e. two error logs). Please provide `Logica.esegui();` implementation. It could be that an application exception is thrown but swallowed.

Comment: Also, is the application deployed in a cluster? Could it be that two nodes of the cluster execute the task in parallel? How do you know the task is actually run twice? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: yes, the method log.sendEmail (); sends me an email at the end of the program, and every day I get 2 at a distance of 1 hour (the processing time of the whole program) then it is started immediately after the end of the first one, also any kind of exception is captured on a file log that is always sent to me via email, and I haven't received any error for days. (the program was successful)

Comment: by rectification, the ottimizza.sql (); method and the log.sendEmail () method;
they cannot make exceptions.
the logica.esegui();  method cannot launch them because they are all captured, and as can be seen from the code any other exceptions would be captured by the try in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class ServerStartStop {

    private ExecutorService es2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future<Void> operazioniAggiornamentoUI =null;
    
    
    @Schedule(hour = "*" ,minute = "*",second = "*/10", persistent = false)
    public void AggiornamentoUI(Timer timerInfo) {
        
        if (operazioniAggiornamentoUI!=null)
            if(!operazioniAggiornamentoUI.isDone())
                return;
        
        
        Callable<Void> callableObj = () -> { try {

            GestoreAcquisizioneOrdiniUI.aggiornaUiAcquisizioneOrdini();
            
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        };
        
        
        
        operazioniAggiornamentoUI=es2.submit(callableObj);
        
        
        
        
    }}
```